# Correct way to map random number to defined range?

Tags: random-number-generator

Say that we have a secure random number generation that outputs 32 bit random numbers, so it's output is a true random number between 0 and a MAX.

What is the best way to map this random number to a defined range (say I want something random between X and Y) without loosing too much entropy?

Comment: This seems to be essentially a duplicate of http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5708/351  Ideally, the two would be merged.

Comment: Note to self: this should expanded by an answer that describes [NIST SP800-90Rev1: A.5 Converting Random Bits into a Random Number](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $m = Y-X$. Generating a random integer in the $X$ to $Y$ range is equivalent to generating a random integer in the $0$ to $m$ range (if you generate $r$, then just use $r+X$). For ease of notation, I assume that the low boundary is included and the high boundary is excluded (you want a random $s$ such that $X \leq s \lt Y$).

In most cases, you cannot get a truly uniform random generation by processing a fixed number $n$ of 32-bit integers. Indeed, $n$ 32-bit integers represent exactly $2^{32n}$ possible outcomes. If $m$ is not a power of $2$, then $2^{32m}$ cannot be divided into $m$ sets of identical cardinal.

The usual method is a rejection process:

1. Let $u$ be such that $2^u \geq m$.
2. Let $t = m \times \lfloor \frac{2^u}{m} \rfloor$.
3. Generate $x$, a $u$-bit value (from your generator of 32-bit integers, just append 32-bit values until you reach the size $u$ or more, and truncate to $u$ bits). We have $0 \leq x \lt 2^u$.
4. If $x \geq t$ then loop to the previous step.
5. Return $r = x \mod m$.

The idea of the method is that the $2^u$ range is split into a sub-range of size $t$ (a multiple of $m$) and another sub-range (of size less than $m$). If the $u$-bit value $x$ fall in the first sub-range, then you take it modulo $m$, which yields a uniform value since $t$ is a multiple of $m$. Otherwise, you just discard $x$ and try again. With the constraints above, it can easily be seen that the probability of $x$ falling in the wrong sub-range is less then $0.5$, so the average number of invocations of the PRNG will be less than $2$ (less than two invocations for a $k$-bit integer, which may involve a lot of invocations of the underlying PRNG which produces only 32 bits at a time, depending on your parameters).

**Then you have a choice**, namely what $u$ to use. One extreme is to use the smallest possible $u$, i.e. $2^{u-1} \lt m \leq 2^u$. This is the choice that maximizes the average number of loops; however, it means that the final "modulo" operation is a no-operation (with $u$ as small as possible, you have $t = m$). For small parameters ($m$ is less then 32 bits), this is often an appropriate choice, because PRNG invocations are usually cheaper than integer division (if you use an efficient PRNG, such as [these ones](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/), of course).

The other extreme is to make $u$ much bigger, so that the probability that $x$ falls in the wrong range becomes negligible; at that point, you can often just skip the computation of $t$ and the test $x \geq t$, and proceed directly to the modulo operation: this will imply a slight bias, but a bias lower than what can be detected, let alone be acted upon.

See [DSA](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf), annex B.2: for each DSA (or ECDSA) signature, a new value $k$ must be generated for each signature, in the $1$ to $q-1$ range (inclusive), and it must be as uniform as possible. The annex presents the two methods, one with 64 bits of extra space ($u \geq 64 + \log q$), the other with the smallest possible $u$. Which one is preferable is a question of performance and convenience; a DSA implementation (as opposed to ECDSA) must have some code to reduce big values modulo $q$, so using the extra bits is probably simplest; ECDSA implementations, on the other hand, especially hardware implementations which work with binary fields, will probably prefer the "small $u$" method. For *security*, both are safe.

Comment: This algorithm is great when random input is cheap, and is most used; for example by `java.util.Random.nextint(int n)`, with $u=31$. But it often consumes significantly more input than necessary, and that's an issue in some applications (e.g when the input is expensive/slow, e.g. coins throws). [This](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5721/555), while remaining practical, manages to reduce $u$ dynamically when possible, which is most often; and recycling some (not all) of the previously gathered entropy, rather than loosing it as occurs at step 4 when looping back; it is not optimal, though.