# Generating a NIST P-256 private key

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-generation

From the Curve25519 spec I learned that it possible to take a random 32 bytes and with a few operations make it on the curve:

To generate a 32-byte Curve25519 secret key, start by generating 32 secret random bytes from a cryptographically safe source:

```
mysecret[0], mysecret[1], ..., mysecret[31].
```

Then do

```
mysecret[0] &= 248;
mysecret[31] &= 127;
mysecret[31] |= 64;
```

Is there a similar way to take random bytes and use it for a p-256 private key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A NIST P-256 secret key (for ECDH or ECDSA) represents any scalar modulo $\ell$ for $$\ell = 2^{256} - 2^{224} + 2^{192} - 89188191075325690597107910205041859247,$$ whereas an X25519 secret key represents an integer multiple of 8 between $2^{254}$ and $2^{255}$, interpreted as a scalar modulo $8 p_1$ for $$p_1 = 2^{252}  + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493.$$  In both cases, the secret key should be chosen uniformly at random from all possibilities, so that every possibility has equal probability.  Here $\ell$ and $p_1$, both large primes, are the orders of the standard base points on the respective curves.

The NIST recommends, in [FIPS 186-4](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.186-4) Appendix B.4 pp. 61–64, that you either generate 320 bits uniformly at random, reduce modulo $\ell - 1$, and add $1$; or do rejection sampling, drawing 256-bit $n$ and starting over unless $0 < n < \ell$.  These methods keep the [modulo bias](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50580/49826) respectively either small or nonexistent, and avoid $n = 0$.  The benefit of this negligible, so I would just accept the modulo bias of picking 256 bits uniformly at random and performing a single conditional subtraction, losing less than a single bit of theoretical security.  But if you're using NIST P-256, you're probably slave to compliance with government bureaucracy standards, so you should probably follow the letter of the standard.

**Technical details**, or, why is it different for (say) ECDH over NIST P-256 and X25519?

The curve group NIST P-256 has prime order $\ell$, and the standard base point generates the entire group, so even if you reveal $[n]P$ for attacker-controlled points $P$ where $n$ is your secret scalar, there are no [active small-subgroup attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51352/49826) possible on NIST P-256; and although the quadratic twist of NIST P-256 does not have prime order, it happens to have the modest cofactor $34905 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 179$ which confers a degree of [twist security](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html).  Caveat: If you foolishly handle uncompressed $(x, y)$ inputs, twist security is not enough; you must still validate them to thwart *invalid-curve* attacks.

In contrast, the curve group Curve25519 has *composite* order $8 p_1$, and its twist has composite order $4 p_2$ for another large prime $p_2$, while the standard base point has order $p_1$.  So to thwart small-subgroup and twist attacks *without* requiring point validation, the secret scalar $n$ is always chosen to be congruent to zero modulo the cofactor 8 and the twist cofactor 4, and public keys are transmitted as $x$ coordinates only so the only possible invalid curve is the quadratic twist.

Comment: "NIST recommends ... either generate 320 bits uniformly at random and reduce modulo $\ell$", actually, their recommendation actually is "reduce it modulo $\ell-1$, and then add 1 (obviously to reduce the probability of generating 0 from negligible to impossible)

Comment: @poncho UGH!  Bureaucratic standardsese AND fenceposts with probability near $2^{-256}$!

Comment: Yeah, you might as well amend it with an additional check that the answer isn't 1 or N-1 as something is *clearly* wrong if it ever reaches either of those values :P

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Holy key generation, Bodewesman!  What if it turns out to be 21397745653766824805525653055986092741404767722902725289987975828237449574345, which is the concatenation of the last handful of serial numbers I saw on boxes and parcels while going through the recycling?  Better check for that number too—especially now that it's posted on the internet where Google can find it!

Comment: Why is it OK for Curve25519 to choose a random number $2^{254} \le x < 2^{255}$ (divisible by 8), while P-256 needs a random number $0 < x < \ell$? In other words, why can Curve25519 ignore the numbers between $0$ and $2^{254}$ and between $2^{255}$ and $\ell$?

Comment: @Conrado, you might be wondering why it's ok to make the range of possible numbers smaller. In absolute terms, the range is about 16 times smaller than it would otherwise be, yes. But in terms of bits, that means you've got 252 bits of randomness instead of 256. That's a pretty small difference.

Comment: @JackO'Connor my comment is more about bias than entropy. Why the P-256 key must be carefully chosen uniformly inside the whole range, while for Curve25519 is enough to generate inside a subset of the whole range? Would it be OK to do the same with P-256?

Comment: @Conrado: P-256 is often used with ECDSA, and that's susceptible to attack with relatively small bias in the choice of the per-signature private key. Such bias is less an issue with EdDSA and not much an issue with ECDH (independently of the curve).

Comment: @fgrieu but this question is about the long-term private key, isn't it? AFAIK the nonce is supposed to be uniformly random in both P-256 and EdDSA

Comment: @Conrado: my remark is because in ECDSA as specified by FIPS 186-4 and -5, the method in the answer is applied (also) to generate the per-signature private key. This can explain the extreme attention to uniformity, which makes little sense for a long-term private key.